# Wakanda and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, wakanda

I'm working on a business app using Wakanda Studio.
I was interested in turning the app into a real android/iPhone app, my idea was to make a browser shell with the app inside. BUT, I stumbled upon Phonegap and a guide to extend Wakanda with Phonegap, neither of which I have much experience with (Phonegap, 0).
The guide loses me at the "click the Extension button" under the "What the Extension Does" heading:
http://www.sitepoint.com/cut-mobile-app-dev-time-with-phonegap-wakanda-studio-extension/

I feel like a noob for not having more information for you, but I've scoured the entire Wakanda app menus looking for information, as well as Google, and the Wakanda documentation. I am dedicated to using this Studio to deploy a business app! Please share your knowledge!

Comment: The mystery continues:http://i.imgur.com/1FMazwd.png

Answer (score 3):

Wakanda Studio now integrates, by default, a full mobile app workflow.
In particular, it's based on:

- [**Cordova**](http://cordova.apache.org/) (formerly PhoneGap)
- [**Ionic**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/)

This tutorial illustrates the integration:

- [**Mobile Apps with Wakanda**](http://wakanda.github.io/wakanda-studio/create-mobile-app.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reference is to this Wakanda Studio Extension:
http://www.sitepoint.com/cut-mobile-app-dev-time-with-phonegap-wakanda-studio-extension/

When you install the extension you will get a button to create a PhoneGap/Cordova package from your wakanda solution. Then the "click the Extension button" will become meaningful to you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, add some reasons why this answers the question and it'd be a better answer!